# A comment after the xsim solution environment is being printed

Tags: bugs, xsim

If I add a comment after the `solution` environment of the `xsim` package the comment is printed before the solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}
   \begin{exercise} % execice 1
      Statement of exercise 1 
   \end{exercise}
   \begin{solution}[print] % I need a comment here
      Solution of exercise 1 
   \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package has a github site where bugs can be reported. But probably is it a side effect of the verbatim reading and writing of the content and difficult to avoid. Put the comment on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is not a bug. It is a side effect of the contents being read verbatim and then being written to an external file.

Actually, this is mentioned in the manual (section 5 about how the exercise environments work):

> Another thing to keep in mind: the environment in many ways works the same way as the `filecontents` environment. This also means that you cannot have comments on the first line of the environments:
>
> ```
> \begin{exercise}[points=2] % this comment will cause trouble
>   Lorem ipsum
> \end{exercise}
> ```

Just put your comments a line further down and you're fine:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  % execice 1
  Statement of exercise 1 
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}[print]
  % I need a comment here
  Solution of exercise 1 
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable details